CORS browser issue: Docker-in-Docker + Fullstack app with Traefik
I am having issues running the tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-template application via docker compose from inside of a devcontainer. When I run docker compose up from my host OS, everything works just fine. However, once I run from inside of a devcontainer, I can access many pages, but trying to make a request from the frontend to the backend results in a CORS error but no discernible log debug statements to hint me towards the solution
The setup is this:
Dev environment

Mac OS X host OS
VS Code IDE
Dev Container running mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:bookworm image

App environment

Traefik proxy
FastAPI backend
React Vite frontend
PostgreSQL database

How I run it

Set the local domain through the /etc/hosts file
If using devcontainer, start the devcontainer and attach VSCode to it
Run docker compose up
If using devcontainer, forward the access ports for frontend, backend, and admin dashboards
Access the frontend site at local.my.domain:
On /login, type username and password, and press enter

The issue

When I submit the login info, I get the following error:

# On Firefox
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://local.my.domain/api/v1/login/access-token. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

# On Chromium
POST http://local.my.domain/api/v1/login/access-token net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

# Docker compose logs
<No logs denoting that any request has been made>

What I've tried

Adding the domain to the container's /etc/hosts file. Same issue
Removing the custom local domain from the .env setup file. Now the site is accessed from localhost, but same issue
Adding many combinations to the BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS variable, which is processed by the backend. Currently it is BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS=["http://localhost","http://localhost:5173","https://localhost","https://localhost:5173","http://localhost.tiangolo.com","http://localhost:54550","http://local.my.domain","http://local.my.domain:54550","https://local.my.domain:54550"], where 54550 is the forwarded domain outside of the devcontainer (inside it is 80)

Other notes

Making a request directly to the docs, either via Swagger or Postman, works
All of the admin dashboards are accessible and work

Questions

What else should I try?
Is this an issue with the browser blocking the request? If so, why would the browser only block the request when the app is running from the Docker-in-Docker environment via the devcontainer?
Is there a Traefik configuration that I might be missing?

